# Javascript bind.apply invocation confuses me

Tags: javascript, apply, bind

Given this code:

```js
const handler = function() {
  console.log(this)
  console.log(this.myName)
  console.log(arguments)
}

const myClass = function() {
    this.myName = "myObject with a name"
}

const myObject = new myClass()

const args = ['these', 'are', 'the', 'arguments']

const oldInvocation = handler.bind.apply( handler, [myObject].concat(args) )
oldInvocation()
```

So apply invokes the bind method. I don't understand why myObject is treated as this argument and the rest of the array ('these' 'are' 'the' 'arguments' ) as the arguments. They are all inside the same array. Why is the first element of the array used as this and not the handler?

The invocation here should be the same, correct?

```
const oldInvocation = handler.bind.apply( handler, [myObject, 'these', 'are', 'the', 'arguments'] )
```

Comment: Is the equivalent `call` call clearer: `handler.bind.call(handler, myObject, 'these', 'are', 'the', 'arguments');`? Think about how `call` calls the function `handler.bind`.

Comment: Review the arguments to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not clearer to me. If I call bind, the first argument is used as ```this```, here it's ```handler``` and myObject would be just a normal argument prepended to the later invocation? But that seems not to be the case, instead handler is used as a function and myObject will be used as this for that handler function. But I don't know why.